# PHP foreach loop adding extra loop and how to return new array from within

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional php array that stores the opening and closing times of my shop. The array contains other data about the shop to however in this particular function I am trying to create a new array with only the day as an index value and the open and close hours as an array. Like the following

```
$hours = array(
    'mon' => array('11:00-23:00'), 
    'tue' => array('11:00-23:00'),
    'wed' => array('11:00-22:30'),
    'thu' => array('11:00-02:30'),
    'fri' => array('11:00-02:30'),
    'sat' => array('11:00-02:30'),
    'sun' => '', 
);
```

My current foreach with a for loop goes through my existing array and returns a variable for each day, open and close time. However I have included just a simple print at the bottom for debugging purposes. Everytime the foreach returns the correct day: open to close however it always returns one extra :to as if it's doing an extra loop. I have dumped the original array and every time it returns an array with (7) as the count. Secondly what is the most efficient way to return an array like the one above from within this foreach for loop.

```
foreach ($this -> entries as $entry) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($entry); $i++) {
        $day = $entry[$i]['day_open']['value'];
        $open = $entry[$i]['open_hour']['value'];
        $close = $entry[$i]['close_hour']['value'];
        print $day . " : " . $open . " to " . $close . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Here is the var_dump of $this -> entries

```
array(3) { ["entries"]=> array(7) { 
    [0]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["created"]=> int(1418692508) ["updated"]=> bool(false) ["created_by"]=> string(1) "1" ["ordering_count"]=> string(1) "1" ["close_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "10pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" } ["open_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "2pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" } ["day_open"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "Sun" ["val"]=> string(3) "Sun" ["value"]=> string(3) "Sun" } ["last"]=> string(1) "0" ["odd_even"]=> string(3) "odd" ["count"]=> int(1) } 
    [1]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["created"]=> int(1418692519) ["updated"]=> int(1418698391) ["created_by"]=> string(1) "1" ["ordering_count"]=> string(1) "2" ["close_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "10pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" } ["open_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "2pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" } ["day_open"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "Mon" ["val"]=> string(3) "Mon" ["value"]=> string(3) "Mon" } ["last"]=> string(1) "0" ["odd_even"]=> string(4) "even" ["count"]=> int(2) } 
    [2]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["created"]=> int(1418692525) ["updated"]=> bool(false) ["created_by"]=> string(1) "1" ["ordering_count"]=> string(1) "3" ["close_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "10pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" } ["open_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "2pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" } ["day_open"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "Tue" ["val"]=> string(3) "Tue" ["value"]=> string(3) "Tue" } ["last"]=> string(1) "0" ["odd_even"]=> string(3) "odd" ["count"]=> int(3) } 
    [3]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["created"]=> int(1418692529) ["updated"]=> bool(false) ["created_by"]=> string(1) "1" ["ordering_count"]=> string(1) "4" ["close_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "10pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" } ["open_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "2pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" } ["day_open"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "Wed" ["val"]=> string(3) "Wed" ["value"]=> string(3) "Wed" } ["last"]=> string(1) "0" ["odd_even"]=> string(4) "even" ["count"]=> int(4) } 
    [4]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["created"]=> int(1418692536) ["updated"]=> bool(false) ["created_by"]=> string(1) "1" ["ordering_count"]=> string(1) "5" ["close_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "10pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "10:00 PM" } ["open_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "2pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" } ["day_open"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "Thu" ["val"]=> string(3) "Thu" ["value"]=> string(3) "Thu" } ["last"]=> string(1) "0" ["odd_even"]=> string(3) "odd" ["count"]=> int(5) } 
    [5]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["created"]=> int(1418692549) ["updated"]=> int(1418698491) ["created_by"]=> string(1) "1" ["ordering_count"]=> string(1) "6" ["close_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "12am" ["val"]=> string(8) "12:00 AM" ["value"]=> string(8) "12:00 AM" } ["open_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "2pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" } ["day_open"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "Fri" ["val"]=> string(3) "Fri" ["value"]=> string(3) "Fri" } ["last"]=> string(1) "0" ["odd_even"]=> string(4) "even" ["count"]=> int(6) } 
    [6]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["created"]=> int(1418692559) ["updated"]=> int(1418698459) ["created_by"]=> string(1) "1" ["ordering_count"]=> string(1) "7" ["close_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "12am" ["val"]=> string(8) "12:00 AM" ["value"]=> string(8) "12:00 AM" } ["open_hour"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "2pm" ["val"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" ["value"]=> string(8) "02:00 PM" } ["day_open"]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(3) "Sat" ["val"]=> string(3) "Sat" ["value"]=> string(3) "Sat" } ["last"]=> string(1) "1" ["odd_even"]=> string(3) "odd" ["count"]=> int(7) } 
    } 
    ["pagination"]=> NULL ["total"]=> int(7) 
}
```

and in print_r

```
Array ( [entries] => Array (
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [created] => 1418692508 [updated] => [created_by] => 1 [ordering_count] => 1 [close_hour] => Array ( [key] => 10pm [val] => 10:00 PM [value] => 10:00 PM ) [open_hour] => Array ( [key] => 2pm [val] => 02:00 PM [value] => 02:00 PM ) [day_open] => Array ( [key] => Sun [val] => Sun [value] => Sun ) [last] => 0 [odd_even] => odd [count] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [created] => 1418692519 [updated] => 1418698391 [created_by] => 1 [ordering_count] => 2 [close_hour] => Array ( [key] => 10pm [val] => 10:00 PM [value] => 10:00 PM ) [open_hour] => Array ( [key] => 2pm [val] => 02:00 PM [value] => 02:00 PM ) [day_open] => Array ( [key] => Mon [val] => Mon [value] => Mon ) [last] => 0 [odd_even] => even [count] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [created] => 1418692525 [updated] => [created_by] => 1 [ordering_count] => 3 [close_hour] => Array ( [key] => 10pm [val] => 10:00 PM [value] => 10:00 PM ) [open_hour] => Array ( [key] => 2pm [val] => 02:00 PM [value] => 02:00 PM ) [day_open] => Array ( [key] => Tue [val] => Tue [value] => Tue ) [last] => 0 [odd_even] => odd [count] => 3 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [created] => 1418692529 [updated] => [created_by] => 1 [ordering_count] => 4 [close_hour] => Array ( [key] => 10pm [val] => 10:00 PM [value] => 10:00 PM ) [open_hour] => Array ( [key] => 2pm [val] => 02:00 PM [value] => 02:00 PM ) [day_open] => Array ( [key] => Wed [val] => Wed [value] => Wed ) [last] => 0 [odd_even] => even [count] => 4 ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [created] => 1418692536 [updated] => [created_by] => 1 [ordering_count] => 5 [close_hour] => Array ( [key] => 10pm [val] => 10:00 PM [value] => 10:00 PM ) [open_hour] => Array ( [key] => 2pm [val] => 02:00 PM [value] => 02:00 PM ) [day_open] => Array ( [key] => Thu [val] => Thu [value] => Thu ) [last] => 0 [odd_even] => odd [count] => 5 ) 
[5] => Array ( [id] => 6 [created] => 1418692549 [updated] => 1418698491 [created_by] => 1 [ordering_count] => 6 [close_hour] => Array ( [key] => 12am [val] => 12:00 AM [value] => 12:00 AM ) [open_hour] => Array ( [key] => 2pm [val] => 02:00 PM [value] => 02:00 PM ) [day_open] => Array ( [key] => Fri [val] => Fri [value] => Fri ) [last] => 0 [odd_even] => even [count] => 6 ) 
[6] => Array ( [id] => 7 [created] => 1418692559 [updated] => 1418698459 [created_by] => 1 [ordering_count] => 7 [close_hour] => Array ( [key] => 12am [val] => 12:00 AM [value] => 12:00 AM ) [open_hour] => Array ( [key] => 2pm [val] => 02:00 PM [value] => 02:00 PM ) [day_open] => Array ( [key] => Sat [val] => Sat [value] => Sat ) [last] => 1 [odd_even] => odd [count] => 7 )
) 
[pagination] => [total] => 7 )
```

Comment: Show the original `$this->entries` array.

Comment: Can you show us your $this->entries?

Comment: added var_dump to the original question

Comment: How would I remove that?

Comment: Can you give the array in the format of print_r?

Comment: added print_r format

Comment: After reading my own again I realized that the CMS is returning `$this->entries` with an array in it of `entries` so I am now using `$this -> entries['entries']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking only a few from that ghastly array:

```
$oldArray = array(
    "entries"=> array(
        array( 
            "id"=>"1", 
            "created"=> 1418692508, 
            "updated"=> false, 
            "created_by"=> "1", 
            "ordering_count"=> "1",
            "close_hour" => array(
                "key"=> "10pm",
                "val"=> "10:00 PM",
                "value"=> "10:00 PM" 
            ),
            "open_hour"=> array(
                "key"=> "2pm",
                "val"=> "02:00 PM",
                "value"=> "02:00 PM"
            ),
            "day_open"=> array(
                "key"=> "Mon",
                "val"=> "Mon",
                "value"=> "Mon"
            ),
            "last"=> "0",
            "odd_even"=> "odd",
            "count"=> 1 
        ), 
        array( 
            "id"=>"1", 
            "created"=> 1418692508, 
            "updated"=> false, 
            "created_by"=> "1", 
            "ordering_count"=> "1",
            "close_hour" => array(
                "key"=> "10pm",
                "val"=> "10:00 PM",
                "value"=> "10:00 PM" 
            ),
            "open_hour"=> array(
                "key"=> "2pm",
                "val"=> "02:00 PM",
                "value"=> "02:00 PM"
            ),
            "day_open"=> array(
                "key"=> "Tues",
                "val"=> "Tues",
                "value"=> "Tues"
            ),
            "last"=> "0",
            "odd_even"=> "odd",
            "count"=> 1 
        ), 
        array( 
            "id"=>"1", 
            "created"=> 1418692508, 
            "updated"=> false, 
            "created_by"=> "1", 
            "ordering_count"=> "1",
            "close_hour" => array(
                "key"=> "10pm",
                "val"=> "10:00 PM",
                "value"=> "10:00 PM" 
            ),
            "open_hour"=> array(
                "key"=> "2pm",
                "val"=> "02:00 PM",
                "value"=> "02:00 PM"
            ),
            "day_open"=> array(
                "key"=> "Weds",
                "val"=> "Weds",
                "value"=> "Weds"
            ),
            "last"=> "0",
            "odd_even"=> "odd",
            "count"=> 1 
        ),  
    ),
    "pagination"=> NULL,
    "total"=> 7  
);
$hours = array();
foreach ($oldArray['entries'] as $e) {
        $h = '';
        if (isset($e['open_hour']['value'])) {
            $h = $e['open_hour']['value'].'-'.$e['close_hour']['value'];
        }

        $hours[$e['day_open']['value']] = array(
            $h,
        );
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($hours);
```

prints the following:

```
Array
(
    [Mon] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02:00 PM-10:00 PM
        )

    [Tues] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02:00 PM-10:00 PM
        )

    [Weds] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02:00 PM-10:00 PM
        )

)
```

Comment: Ya the CMS does put a lot of extra detail into the array that I am trying to cut out

Answer (score 0):

Like I thought the

```
["pagination"]=> NULL ["total"]=> int(7)
```

was the problem giving you an extra row, simply only go through the array if you have days

```
if(count($entry) == 7)
```

Here is your code modified:

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {

  if(count($entry) == 7)
  {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($entry); $i++) {
        $day = $entry[$i]['day_open']['value'];
        $open = $entry[$i]['open_hour']['value'];
        $close = $entry[$i]['close_hour']['value'];
        print $day . " : " . $open . " to " . $close . "<br>";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have that in my script already for the new array. However my problem is getting that $days array from my existing array

Comment: @user1881482, I've fixed your original code and found the problem

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? If I understood your dump correctly...

```
$days = [];
foreach ($this-entries["entries"] as $entry) {
    $days[strtolower($entry['day_open']['value'])] = [
        sprintf(
            "%s-%s", 
            substr($entry['open_hour']['value'], 0, 5), 
            substr($entry['close_hour']['value'], 0, 5)
        )
    ];
}
var_dump($days);
```

Comment: @user1881482 Aye. :) Next time you might want to provide a dump of arrays with json_encode. Makes testing code easier.